# Custom slider positioning elements over it.(HTML+CSS)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, slider

Creating a custom slider which should be supporting Chrome and IE11.
Facing issues positioning the thumb and elements(White circle and red oval) on the slider track.
The white circles should be connected with a line.

Here is the fiddle of what i have achieved.

https://jsfiddle.net/Pravin_it14/7t9bsrdn/7/

```css
/*Slider*/

.areaDetail_graph_04 {
  height: 87px;
  width: 614px!important;
  position: relative;
  /* background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); */
  /* border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px; */
}

.areaDetail_graph_04 .img {
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
  height: 87px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  width: 614px!important;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.range {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 614px!important;
}

.range-labels {
  margin: 55px -20px 0 5px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 614px!important;
}

.range-labels li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #808093;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.range-labels li::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -35px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0px;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #E9EEF0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.range-labels li:nth-child(1):before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -42px;
  right: 0;
  left: -20px;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 35px;
  height: 23px;
  background: #F06C81;
  border-radius: 40%;
}

.range-labels li:nth-child(2):before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -42px;
  right: 0;
  left: -20px;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 35px;
  height: 23px;
  background: #F06C81;
  border-radius: 40%;
}

.range-labels li:nth-child(3):before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -42px;
  right: 0;
  left: -20px;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 35px;
  height: 23px;
  background: #F06C81;
  border-radius: 40%;
}

.range-labels li:nth-child(4):before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -42px;
  right: 0;
  left: -20px;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 35px;
  height: 23px;
  background: #F06C81;
  border-radius: 40%;
}

.range-labels li:nth-child(5):before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -42px;
  right: 0;
  left: -35px;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 35px;
  height: 23px;
  background: #F06C81;
  border-radius: 40%;
}

.range-labels li:nth-child(6):before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -42px;
  right: 0;
  left: -50px;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 35px;
  height: 23px;
  background: #826AA7;
  border-radius: 40%;
}

.range-labels li::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -35px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0px;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  background: #E9EEF0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0px 0 0 30px;
  width: 88%;
  z-index: 9999;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  height: 2px;
  background: #E9EEF0;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  position: relative;
  height: 29px;
  width: 29px;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 9999;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -14px;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 16px 0;
  color: transparent;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #E9EEF0;
  border: 0.2px solid#E9EEF0;
  border-radius: 2.6px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #E9EEF0, 0px 0px 1px #E9EEF0;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #E9EEF0;
  border: 0.2px solid #E9EEF0;
  border-radius: 2.6px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #E9EEF0, 0px 0px 1px #E9EEF0;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99999;
  border: transparent;
  height: 29px;
  width: 29px;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url("../parts/icons/handle.png");
}

input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #E9EEF0;
}

input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #E9EEF0;
}
```

```html
<div class="areaDetail_graph_04">
  <div class="img">
    <div class="range">
      <input type="range" class="slider" width="614px" value="0" min="0" max="5" id="rangeSlider">
    </div>
    <ul class="range-labels">
      <li>11:00</li>
      <li>12:00</li>
      <li>13:00</li>
      <li>14:00</li>
      <li>15:00</li>
      <li>16:00</li>

    </ul>
    <span id="valBox"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to provide left:-22px to the 5th and 6th li children. I don't quite understand what does "The white circles should be connected with a line." mean. Have you written any css to achieve this?

Comment: I expect output something similar to this fiddle. https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/GgPjXr

Comment: Try https://jsfiddle.net/8z4hpe3q/3/

Comment: Actually a better version https://jsfiddle.net/9vp1x65c/5/

Comment: I test and your code work in IE but not in Chrome, right? I'm in favor of jill's answer if you mean the white line doesn't cross the white dots in Chrome. If not, please clarify more detaily so that we can have a better understanding of your purpose.

Comment: Yes i was expecting something similar to kokila fiddle. Just the track is not on sync with the circles.

Comment: It should work both on both chrome and IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean the white circle is behind the white line?

You could try adding "margin-bottom: -15px;" to 
"input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track";

In addition, you'd better change the position of the circles inside li(5) and li (6).

use "left: -20px;"both in "li:nth-child(5)" and "li:nth-child(6)".

The complete code is as follows:

```css
/*Slider*/

.areaDetail_graph_04 {
  height: 87px;
  width: 614px!important;
  position: relative;
  
  /* background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); */
  /* border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px; */
}


.areaDetail_graph_04 .img {
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
  height: 87px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  width: 614px!important;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  
}


.range {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 614px!important;
}

.range-labels {
  margin: 55px -20px 0 5px; 
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  width: 614px!important;
}


.range-labels li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #808093;
  
 
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.range-labels li::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -35px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0px;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #E9EEF0;
  
  border-radius: 50%;
}


.range-labels li:nth-child(1):before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -42px;
  right: 0;
  left: -10px;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 35px;
  height: 23px;
  background: #F06C81;
  border-radius: 40%;
}

.range-labels li:nth-child(2):before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -42px;
  right: 0;
  left: -10px;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 35px;
  height: 23px;
  background: #F06C81;
  border-radius: 40%;
}

.range-labels li:nth-child(3):before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -42px;
  right: 0;
  left: -4px;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 35px;
  height: 23px;
  background: #F06C81;
  border-radius: 40%;
}

.range-labels li:nth-child(4):before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -42px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0px;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 35px;
  height: 23px;
  background: #F06C81;
  border-radius: 40%;
}

.range-labels li:nth-child(5):before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -42px;
  right: 0;
  /*left: -35px;*/
  left: 6px;

  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 35px;
  height: 23px;
  background: #F06C81;
  border-radius: 40%;
}

.range-labels li:nth-child(6):before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -42px;
  right: 0;
  /*left: -50px;*/
  left: 8px;

  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 35px;
  height: 23px;
  background: #826AA7;
  border-radius: 40%;
}



/*White circle01*/
.range-labels li:nth-child(1):after {
  
  left: -6px;
  
}

/*White circle02*/
.range-labels li:nth-child(2):after {
  
  left: -10px;
 
}

/*White circle03*/
.range-labels li:nth-child(3):after {
  
  left: -1px;
 
}

/*White circle04*/
.range-labels li:nth-child(4):after {
  
  left: 0px;
 
}
/*White circle05*/
.range-labels li:nth-child(5):after {
  
  left: 7px;
 
}
/*White circle06*/
.range-labels li:nth-child(6):after {
  
  left: 10px;
 
}

/*White circle*/
.range-labels li::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -35px;
  right: 0px;
  /*left: 0px;*/
  content: "";
  margin: 0px auto;
 
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  background: #E9EEF0;
 
  border-radius: 50%;
}


input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: -10px 0px 0px 35px;
  width: 88%;
  z-index: 9999;
  
}


input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
 
  
 
}


input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  height: 2px;
 
  background: #E9EEF0;

  width:100%;
  margin-bottom: -15px;    /*add*/
  /*margin-right: -5px;*/
  
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  
}


input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  position: relative;
  height: 29px;
  width: 29px;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 9999;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -14px;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);

}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  margin-top: -10px;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 16px 0;
  color: transparent;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #E9EEF0;
  
  border: 0.2px solid#E9EEF0;
  
  border-radius: 2.6px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #E9EEF0, 0px 0px 1px #E9EEF0;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #E9EEF0;
 
  border: 0.2px solid #E9EEF0;
  border-radius: 2.6px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #E9EEF0, 0px 0px 1px #E9EEF0;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99999;
  border: transparent;
  height: 29px;
  width: 29px;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url("../parts/icons/handle.png");
}

input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #E9EEF0;

}

input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
 background: #E9EEF0;

}
```

```html
<div class="areaDetail_graph_04">
    <div class="img">
      <div class="range">
       <input type="range" class="slider" width="614px" value="0" min="0" max="5" id="rangeSlider">
       
      </div>
      <ul class="range-labels">
        <li>11:00</li>
        <li>12:00</li>
        <li>13:00</li>
        <li>14:00</li>
        <li>15:00</li>
        <li>16:00</li>
  
      </ul>
      <span id="valBox"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi Jill Thanks for the code. But i need to position all the elements not just the cross-line. White circles should be on center, and the cross lines should start and end correctly in the white circles. Also the slider thumb position should be centered as well. Should be in sync with the track.

Comment: According to your description, I edited the code again.
I set the position of each white circle separately to make them centered.